# Why is Alpha/Beta pruning having no effect on my MiniMax algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

First off I'm sorry for the slightly incorrect title, I just didn't want it to be 30 words long.
The alpha/beta pruning I implemented enormously reduced the amount of evaluations when I applied it to my TicTacToe game, see for yourself below.

Each pair of evaluation counts are measured with the same game state as input.

[image: Pruning vs no pruning]

The problem arises when I want to implement the pruning to the Checkers playing Neural Network I've been working on. Which was the goal of this whole thing to begin with, I just whipped up the TicTacToe game to experiment with MiniMax + Alpha/Beta as I've never dealt with these algorithms before.

Here is the same sort of experiment with the NN.

[image: checkers minimax evals][image: checkers minimax with pruning evals]

Now for the code (checkers one, let me know if you want to have a peek at the TicTacToe version, they are almost identical though).

I'll paste only once the beginning of both methods as they are absolutely identical, I will show both signatures as they differ slightly.

> Small note to make the code more clear.
>
> **Board** is the object which keeps track of pieces, available moves,
>   which turn it is, if the game has been won/drawn etc...
>
> **Move** is the object which contains all information pertinent to moves, when I make
>   the clone as the first line of the method I simply make a clone of the
>   given board and the constructor applies the given move to it.

```
private double miniMax(Board b, Move m, int depth) {
```

and

```
private double alphaBeta(Board b, Move m, int depth, double alpha, double beta) {
```

beginning of both  methods:

```
Testboard clone = new Testboard(b, m);
    // Making a clone of the board in order to
    // avoid making changes to the original one

    if (clone.isGameOver()) {

        if (clone.getLoser() == null) 
            // It's a draw, evaluation = 0
            return 0;   

        if (clone.getLoser() == Color.BLACK)
            // White (Max) won, evaluation = 1
            return 1;

        // Black (Min) won, evaluation = -1
        return -1;  
    } 

    if (depth == 0) 
        // Reached the end of the search, returning current Evaluation of the board
        return getEvaluation(clone);
```

Regular MiniMax continuation:

```
    // If it's not game over
    if (clone.getTurn() == Color.WHITE) {

        // It's white's turn (Maxing player)
        double max = -1;
        for (Move move : clone.getMoves()) {
            // For each children node (available moves)
            // Their minimax value is calculated
            double score = miniMax(clone, move, depth-1);
            // Only the highest score is stored
            if (score > max)
                max = score;
        }
        // And is returned
        return max;
    } 

    // It's black's turn (Min player)
    double min = 1;
    for (Move move : clone.getMoves()) {
        // For each children node (available moves)
        // Their minimax value is calculated
        double score = miniMax(clone, move, depth-1);
        // Only the lowest score is stored
        if (score < min)
            min = score;
    }
    // And is returned
    return min;
}
```

MiniMax with Alpha/Beta pruning continuation:

```
    // If it's not game over
    if (clone.getTurn() == Color.WHITE) {

        // It's white's turn (Maxing player)
        for (Move move : clone.getMoves()) {

            // For each children node (available moves)
            // Their minimax value is calculated                
            double score = alphaBeta(clone, move, depth-1, alpha, beta);

            if (score > alpha)
                // If this score is greater than alpha
                // It is assigned to alpha as the new highest score
                alpha = score;
            if (alpha >= beta)
                // The cycle is interrupted early if the value of alpha equals or is greater than beta
                break;
        }
        // The alpha value is returned
        return alpha;
    } 

    // It's black's turn (Min player)
    for (Move move : clone.getMoves()) {

        // For each children node (available moves)
        // Their minimax value is calculated            
        double score = alphaBeta(clone, move, depth-1, alpha, beta);

        if (score < beta)
            // If this score is lower than beta
            // It is assigned to beta as the new lowest score
            beta = score;
        if (alpha >= beta)
            // The cycle is interrupted early if the value of alpha equals or is greater than beta
            break;
    }
    // The beta value is returned
    return beta;
}
```

I'm honestly stuck and I'm not sure what I could do to try and figure out what's going on. I've tried the MiniMax+A/B on several different even randomly generated neural networks but I've never seen an improvement when it comes to number of evaluations made. I hope someone here is able to shed some light on this situation, thanks!

Comment: One reason could be move ordering, although I doubt it's the only one. If you try the good moves first a lot more will be pruned.

Comment: @maraca Hi thanks for the response. The moves are randomly ordered, I have done plenty of experimenting and every single time the number of evaluations of minimax with or without alpha/beta is exactly the same. There has to be a more crucial mistake in the code.

What you suggest might sometimes make it so the number of evaluations is the same but I feel like it would not always be the case.

Comment: What is your depth of evaluation? What is your steady-state evaluation function to measure board goodness? Checkers trees can be deep; tic-tac-toe, not so much. Your evaluation function for checkers is essentially giving 0s to all boards; and therefore, no pruning occurs.

Comment: It seems that you only evaluate wins and losses, no real evaluation function. So if there is no win or loss in the depth you calculate then you will look at all moves because every leaf is a draw (from the perspective of your evaluation function).

Comment: @tucuxi Hi! I think you might have missed the part of the code in which I return the evaluation of the board if the depth = 0, check the last few lines of the first snippet of code.

My evaluation function is at this point just a random Neural Network, my goal right now is to cut down on evaluations performed before I start to really train it.

I'm using a depth of 4 in the screenshots above.

Comment: @maraca I'm not sure how both of you are saying the same thing, check out the last line in the first snippet of code, I return the current evaluation of the board if depth = 0. For more detail read my comment in response to tucuxi.

Comment: We are saying more or less the same thing. If the board always evaluates to 0 or a random number then you will probably have to look at all the moves. You can try with just the difference in checkers as evaluation function and +100 and -100 as win/loss and you should be able to prune.

Comment: @maraca I'm not saying you're wrong but I absolutely don't see how random evaluations (determinsitically random, the network is not trained but will always give the  same answer given the same input) of the board are any better or worse when it comes to how many evaluations the algorithm has to perform.

I'm pretty sure if you were to look at the last say 100 leaf nodes and their actual "real" evaluation they would look more or less random. And anyhow I've ran the program plenty of times and it has never skipped a single evaluation of maybe a million+, there must be more to it right?

Comment: @maraca I have tried something similar to what you suggesed and you are correct, there is some pruning happening now. Thank you very much, if you want to type up an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @maraca for helping me figure this out, going to answer myself as he only replied with a comment.

There is nothing wrong with the code that I posted, the problem lies with the evaluation function that I was using once the search reached the depth limit.

I was using a still untrained Neural Network that was essentially just spitting out random values, this forced the MiniMax+A/B to go through all the nodes as there was no consistency with the answers which turns out is what is necessary for pruning to happen.